# How to use api response outside the function in angular

Tags: angular, asynchronous

```
gametimes:any;

ngOnInit(): void {
this.gamewinService.get_current_gameid_time().subscribe(response =>{
      this.gametimes = response;  
      console.log(response);  
});

console.log(this.gametimes) //Undefiend
}
```

I am getting response in 'this.gametimes' but not whenever I am trying to getting this outside the response function its showing undefined.
So, How to access response outside the function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `get_current_gameid_time` returns an observable.
You can use [first](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/first) operators from [RxJs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/) :

```js
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

// [...]

gametimes:any;

async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
  this.gametimes = await this.gamewinService.get_current_gameid_time().pipe(first()).toPromise();
  console.log(this.gametimes) // should not be undefined
}
```